# Extracting data fields from the output of a command using bash

Tags: bash, command, field, extract

In a bash script I'm trying to extract some data fields from the output of a command (in my case iwconfig).

I'd like to create a csv file with the collected values. Like:

```
Timestamp,BitRate,LinkQuality,SignalLevel,Missed beacon,...
1,270 Mb/s,100/100,-51 dBm,0,...
2,300 Mb/s,90/100,-43 dBm,0,...
```

The fields are seperated with two spaces in the iwconfig's output. If I could set the IFS variable to two spaces my problem would be solved. But I don't know if this works.
What would you use to do that? Awk or sed?

Best regards

Comment: sed sounds like it would do the job (assuming you don't have any complex escaping rules for spaces inside strings).

Comment: sed is good. cut might not be good to use because its -d = DELIM requires one delimiter, so two spaces might look like an extra field. Can you post the input?

Comment: Please show some example input. However, awk's default field separator is "whitespace", so it's not an issue that's it's exactly 2 spaces.

Comment: You can't go wrong with perl -pe "s///", all the power of sed without all the escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
  s=$(iwconfig $Interface)
  s=${s//          /  }
  s=${s//  /,}
  OIFS="$IFS"
  IFS=','
  arrIN=(${s//  /,})
  IFS=$OIFS

  for value in "${arrIN[@]}"; do
    echo Value: $value
  done
```

I get this output:

```
Value: wlan0
Value:
Value: IEEE 802.11abgn
Value: ESSID:"Top Gear"
Value:
Value: Mode:Managed
Value: Frequency:2.452 GHz
Value: Access Point: F8:D1:11:71:56:B6
Value:
Value: Bit Rate=1 Mb/s
Value: Tx-Power=15 dBm
Value:
Value: Retry
Value: long limit:7
Value: RTS thr:off
Value: Fragment thr:off
Value: Encryption key:off
Value: Power Management:off
Value: Link Quality=49/70
Value: Signal level=-61 dBm
Value:
Value: Rx invalid nwid:0
Value: Rx invalid crypt:0
Value: Rx invalid frag:0
Value: Tx excessive retries:0
Value: Invalid misc:0
Value: Missed beacon:0
```

Now I can create the line I need directly with e.g.

```
${arrIN[6]#*":"}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: I would use awk. However probably I'd use python and a single regexp to capture all the parameters in a dictionary.

Bonus: I've done the exercise of doing what you want in bash using gnu's grep (the regexps you'll need may vary as the iwconfig output is device dependent):

```
SLEEP=10 # time to sleep between samples

while true; do # or launch it as a cron task
    TIMESTAMP=$(date +'%s')
    IW=$(iwconfig wlan0)

    # capture each parameter in a variable
    IEEE=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=IEEE ).[^\s]*')
    ESSID=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=ESSID:).[^\s]*')
    BITRATE=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=Bit Rate=)\d+\s.[^\s]+(?=[\s]+Tx)')
    TXPOWER=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=Tx-Power=)\d+\s.*')
    RLL=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=limit:)\d')
    RTSTHR=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=RTS thr:).+(?=[ ]+Fra)')
    FRAGTHR=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=Fragment thr:).+')
    TXPOWER=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=Tx-Power=)\d+ .*')
    PM=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=Management:).*')
    LQ=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=Quality=)\d+/\d+')
    SIGLEV=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=level=).*')
    RXNWID=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=nwid:)\d+')
    RXCRYPT=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=crypt:)\d+')
    RXFRAG=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=frag:)\d+')
    RTERET=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=retries:)\d+')
    RTIMISC=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=misc:)\d+')
    RTMBEAC=$(echo "$IW" | grep -oP '(?<=beacon:)\d+')

    #line
    echo $TIMESTAMP,$BITRATE,$LQ,$SIGLEV,$RTMBEAC,...
    sleep $SLEEP
done
```

Example of output:

```
1331848207,54 Mb/s,70/70,-37 dBm ,0,...
1331848217,54 Mb/s,70/70,-35 dBm ,0,...
1331848227,54 Mb/s,70/70,-34 dBm ,0,...
1331848237,54 Mb/s,70/70,-39 dBm ,0,...
1331848247,54 Mb/s,70/70,-35 dBm ,0,...
1331848257,54 Mb/s,70/70,-37 dBm ,0,...
```

Comment: I didn't know that iwconfig's output is device dependent. Thanks for the hint!

Maybe I should have explained earlier: The script will run on a empedded linux system (Gumstix) and I think that grep read the variable each time completely.

Since I know where the fields are I thought of using an array. So I read the output word by word into an array and can access the specific fields directly without reading the whole content of the variable again and again.